# Set an orientation and then forbid rotation

Tags: android

I have an app that works well both horizontally, and vertically.
So I don't want to limit the user to one single orientation, but at the same time I don't want the user to be able to change orientation during app execution.

What I want to do is automatically set the orientation at the very start of the app, according to what the user is using, and then keep it for the all lifecycle, ignoring any change-orientation request.

Either, I could let the user change orientation on the main menu, but forbid it in the single Activities.

The app is made of several Activities and Fragments.

How can I do it?

Thank you.

Comment: That doesn't sound very user friendly. I am not sure many users use their phone in horizontal orientation BEFORE starting an application.

Comment: Perhaps this will help
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10309588/freeze-screen-orientation

Comment: I edited the question according to Maggie's suggestion.